# How to design schema denormalization to handle data changes?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose-schema

I'm designing a schema for MongoDB, and keep running into scenarios where future updates might invalidate my cached copies of data.  One example is for Users, Orders and Addresses.

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    addresses: [{ street: String, city: String, state: String, zip: String }]
});

const OrderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    address: { street: String, city: String, state: String, zip: String }
});
```

This seems to be a standard approach, since MongoDB isn't meant to be a relational database, to denormalize the data where possible.  However, the following scenario confuses me:

1. User adds an Address to their User document.
2. User places an Order and selects an Address from their list of
   addresses.
3. The address data is copied into the Order document when the order is
   persisted.
4. Before the order is shipped, the user discovers that they mistyped
   the address.
5. User changes that incorrect Address in their User document.
6. The Address in the Order object needs to change also, otherwise it
   will be shipped to an invalid address.

This seems to point towards the need for a reference using mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId to simulate a relational structure between the collections.  (In that case, there would also be an Addresses collection, of course.)   However, there are other considerations such as the history aspect of the denormalization.  I want to store the actual address to which the order was shipped, even if that address is later deleted or changed.  With denormalization this would seem to be easier than the relational paradigm.

One approach I considered to create an Addresses collection, then mark its records as invalidated when they are deleted, in case they are already referenced in an Order.  And when they are modified, I would need to check the Orders collection to see if that Address is referenced.  If it's already been referenced in a **shipped** order, I would have to leave it alone (for historical purposes), and create an additional Address document with the new changes.  All of which sounds a bit complicated, compared to the denormalization approach.

The next part of the issue regards querying and reporting.  If I want to pull up a list of all Users who have ever had an address in Illinois, I would need to traverse both the Addresses collection and the Orders in order to find out.  Because they may have had an Illinois address, used it in a shipped order, then deleted it from the Addresses collection.

How do the smartest MongoDB data architects handle situations like this?  I'm an experienced relational database architect, but am somewhat baffled by the conceptual framework of NoSQL.  Thanks!

Comment: Instead of over-complicating your thinking here, why not just make the "Oh, I meant my order to go to **this** address simply be a function of editing the address **on the order itself**. From a transaction point of view that really makes the most logical sense since it's a **point in time** reflection. And "list of addresses" attached to a user account can simply be historical, or as a point of reference for a UI to "pick" a previously used address from. You can even mark a default to copy in the order.

Comment: Bottom line is "which is best?" is not really for others to determine for you, but rather what actually works best for your application and needs. It's not that MongoDB **won't** handle pointing to relational references, but simply that **any "join" has an inherrent cost.** And from that perspective it's really a choice between the **cost of data duplication** ( and maintenance in some cases ) weighed up the **cost of "joining" overheads**. These sort of things are really often best sorted out by ***testing*** the various approaches and seeing which results in the best fit, **for you**.